# Select Codeigniter Output - From Cache or Render View

Tags: codeigniter, caching, codeigniter-2

As I understand Codigniter cache works on matching the URI. Therefore if caching is set in a method that contains a form it will display the empty form all the time.

Is there a way to set whether to display the cache file or render the view?

Pseudocode:

```
if form validation = FALSE
    serve cache file
else
    render view
endif
```

Also is there a way to check if the form is being displayed because it is the first load or if it is being displayed because there are errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Codeigniter caching way, it is not possible to display from cache conditionally. Because Codeigniter decides to display from cache before calling the controller itself.

What you can do is to use your custom caching library. There are several caching libraries for Codeigniter. You can try https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-cache

Answer (score 0):

You can conditionally set your cache from whatever your output gives you. Though it does not render your "view" from cache, but it'll significantly improve your performance if you do any heavy processing on your forms.

For example, you can do this in your *controller*:

```
$this->load->driver('cache');

if (!$this->form_validation->run())
{
    if (!$cache = $this->cache->get('some unique variable'))
    {
        $cache = $this->some_model->some_function();
        // Do your rendering here.
    }
}

$this->load->view('some_view', array('data' => $cache));
```

That way you can use something like file caching, memcached or apc to cache your variables.